# How to visualize the complete xhtml page (assembled from multiple fragments)?

Tags: java, debugging, jsf, xhtml, myfaces

I am currently debugging a JSF application based on XHTML (still on myfaces 1.1 if you are curious).

But our faces are an assembly of many XHTML fragments and sometimes, for the purposes of debuging, it would help a lot knowing how the whole thing looks once all the fragments have been put together.

Do you know any way of visualizing those?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets

Comment: I see a Q&A on how to fragment a XHTML page in multiple fragments (which is already what I am doing), but I don't see where they explain how to visualize the whole thing once pieces have been put together again by JSF?

Comment: Assembling multiple fragments, do you mean, using `ui:include` tags? The best way to see it is debugging and using a web browser. Don't know if there are some wysiwyg tools, but best way is testing it in a real environment.

Comment: yes and `ui:composition` tags as well. I am currently debugging the whole thing step by step, but I miss a tool that would have showned me what the whole thing looks like.